# JSF passing view parameters by reference - when object must be instantiated

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Let's say I've got a register page & a register confirm page. I enter user
details into the register page, navigate to the register confirm page where
I can return back to the register page if there are any mistakes.

I'm going to use view parameters to make the registration data available
from the register page to the confirm page, and vice versa.

Supposing there are 20 items of data to be moving from page to page, that's
a lot of view parameters and a lot of setPropertyActionListeners, especially
as all the data is going to end up nicely packaged in a User object.

So what I want to do is input the data on the register page into the
properties of a User record and send a reference to it to the register
confirm page. What gave me an idea was seeing the BalusC WeakHashMap
converter. This is a JSF converter which has a static weak hash map and
generates a uuid as the value for a map entry and the object reference as
the key. So by specifying this as a converter for f:viewParam you send
the uuid in the query string.

This works fine. The issue I have is that on the register page I have to
get an instance of a User class with new. Then I can do:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.user.firstname}"/>
```

(etc...), and pass the user instance as a view parameter. It works fine from
the register to the confirm page. The issue is that when I perform the
reverse, sending the user reference back to the register page from the
confirm page I absolutely cannot prevent the register page backing bean
from re-instantiating the user object, **after** the setter has been called
as a result of the view parameter.

So the converter does it's job and retrieves the User object from the
hash map, calls setUser() in the backing bean, and then I see the
constructor for the User class firing.

I've tried calling new User() from the bean constructor, in @PostConstruct,
in a preRenderView (also checking if an ajax request), but nothing I try
prevents the work of the view parameter from getting wiped out if new is
involved. I'm sure there's a simple solution but I just can't see it right
now.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions for how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts over more than a year to find a solid long term solution
to this problem, at last! I've found one. The solution comes in the form of the
Apache Myfaces CDI extensions project, aka [Myfaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/).

This provides additional scopes such as the @ViewAccessScoped which ensures that
if a bean is referenced by a page then it is available for that page. Also
provided is support for conversation groups. In the scenario where I want to
pass an object reference from a register page to a register confirm page, the
confirm page can just access the registerView bean directly on the next request.
Alternatively you can @Inject one bean into another and access it on the next
request, or use f:setPropertyActionListener from the source page.

Myfaces CODI works fine with Mojarra and also with ajaxified component libraries
such as primefaces. The concept is similar to what is provided by Jboss Seam,
though I've found the additional scope support to be better thought out and I've
tested this on glassfish 3.1.1 with no problems.

If you're using @ManagedBean and scope annotations from the javax.faces.bean
package in your code, codi intercepts these annotations and uses it's own
CDI based versions, so you can convert to CDI simply by adding codi as a
dependency to your project and not changing any code.

For me this is like moving from black and white TV to colour TV, I wish I'd
found this stuff sooner.

[CODI documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/EXTCDI/jsf-usage.html)

Answer (score 3):

> The issue I have is that on the register page I have to get an instance of a User class with new.

So what code is initially creating this new User instance then? If you do this in the `preRenderView` handler, then you can simply check for null, can't you?

If the view parameter and converter haven't done their job, `user` would still be null and you create a new instance. The bean constructor and `@PostConstruct` won't do you any good here, since they both run before the view parameter does its thing, but the `preRenderView` event is guaranteed to run after it.

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    private User user;

    public void onPreRenderView() {
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
        }
    }
}
```

*(Something to additionally consider is that the `conversation scope` already does exactly what you're trying to do here. This is part of CDI not JSF, but if you're running in a Java EE 6 Web Profile compliant AS (JBoss AS 6 or 7, Glassfish V3, Resin 4, ...) you already have it. Otherwise it's just an extra jar.)*

Comment: Hi Arjan, I'd tried this but alas it didn't work. I spent a few days recently trying to get weld working with glassfish 3.1 but there are too many issues, even with weld 1.1.1. The big issue I have with CDI is the lack of view scope, I guess the way to go is seam 3 @RenderScoped or the Steven Verborgh custom view scope. I've nearly figured this problem out now but it's 3am and I better finish off tomorrow. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: About `@ViewScoped` missing with CDI, yes this is a big issue. But Seam3 adds it again. Unlike Seam2, Seam3 consists of many small portable extensions so you can just add the part to your app that fixes this instead of adding everything. Optionally, if you just need the conversation scope, then only 1 bean can be CDI conversation scoped, and other beans can remain JSF ManagedBeans (but this is not so pretty perhaps).

Comment: The problem is that seam 3 has got a lot of compatibility issues with glassfish 3.0.1/3.1 (http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Compatibility) I spent days trying to get the Verborgh view scope working with CDI, and also Seam 3 @RenderScoped and neither would work with glassfish. With conversation scope I don't really get when to end a conversation, and how do you handle browser back button?. I'm just gonna use the session map. My original issue is that between views the data in the weakhashmap is garbage collected and jsf doesn't call the setter. Thanks for your comments.